# Hide item from popupmenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

I created a popup menu. I need to hide a particular item from popup menu on condition, I tried this below code but it doesn't work and shows *"unexpectedly your app has been stopped"*. I used `findViewById` and `setEnabled(false)`.

Is there any other way to hide an item from popup menu? Please help with this.

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.addMessage_Action:
            AddMessage();
            break;
        case R.id.dropMenuAction:
            menuItemView = findViewById(R.id.dropMenuAction);
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, menuItemView);
            MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.popupmenu_for_message_delete, popup.getMenu());
            popup.show();
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
            if(Global.lock == true)
                findViewById(R.id.lock_message).setEnabled(false);
            else
                findViewById(R.id.unlock_message).setEnabled(false);

            break;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: What does Logcat say?

Comment: Null pointer exception in "findViewById(R.id.lock_message).setEnabled(false);"

Answer (score 57):

You need to get the `Menu` Object from the PopupMenu before you get the item.  So it'd be something like

```
Menu popupMenu = popup.getMenu();
if(Global.lock == true)
    popupMenu.findItem(R.id.lock_message).setEnabled(false);
else 
    popupMenu.findItem(R.id.unlock_message).setEnabled(false);
```

And I'd do this before you call `popup.show()`

Comment: ``getItem`` needs the index as arguement while ``findItem`` takes the id. So the example should be like ``popupMenu.findItem(R.id.lock_message).setEnabled(false);``

Comment: You're right, thanks for the correction.  Updated the original post.

Comment: `popupMenu.findItem(R.id.lock_message).setVisible(false);` will work out. :)

Comment: I was searching a method like this for a long time, and finally today I just found it. Work like a charm in my popup menu to find items by id. Many thanks to the user Tim.

Answer (score 44):

This answer may be helpful to someone,

I used below

```
popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.next).setVisible(true);
```

If you want to change the text of the menu, you can use below code,

```
popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.next).setTitle("After");
```