# SetEnabled(true) in Popup Menu items is not working

Tags: android, spinner, popupmenu

In my app I have a spinner that the user fills it with phone numbers.

The user have 3 options :  *Add* - *Edit* - *Delete*. For displaying the options  i used `popupMenu`.

So, in the beginnging when the spinner in empty, the options *Edit* & *Delete* are enabled (defined in xml file),
but after adding item to spinner i want the enabled options to be available so the user can select them.

I tried some code i found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392916/hide-item-from-popupmenu) but it's not working.

Below is my full code.
Thanks!!!

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class EachApartInList extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener{
    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Menu popupMenu;
    PopupMenu popup;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.each_apart_in_list);
        spinner =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void ShowMenu(View v){

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);

        // This activity implements OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.spinner_action);
        popup.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
        int id;
        switch(id = arg0.getItemId()){
        case R.id.menu_add:
            showAlertDialog();
            break;
        case R.id.menu_edit:
            break;
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            break;

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    void showAlertDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        final EditText phoneNum = new EditText(this);
        phoneNum.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        builder.setView(phoneNum)
        .setTitle("Add number")
        .setMessage("Enter the number here :");
        // Set up the buttons
        builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String newPhoneNum  = phoneNum.getText().toString();

                adapter.add(newPhoneNum);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                popupMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_edit).setEnabled(true);
                popupMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete).setEnabled(true);

            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.show();

    }
```

**spinner_action.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_add"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:title="add"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_edit"
         android:enabled="false" 
        android:title="edit"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
         android:enabled="false" 
        android:title="delete"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the beginning i defined the *edit & delete* options in the **spinner_action.xml**

to : `android:enabled ="false"` and i tried changing them programmingly in `showAlertDialog()` method:

```
void showAlertDialog(){
    .
    .
    .
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            popupMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_edit).setEnabled(true);
            popupMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_delete).setEnabled(true);

        }
    });

}
```

and after the user filled the spinner for the first time he can display again the popupMenu and select other options.But this is the mistake when the user clicks on the button for displaying the popupMenu this code will be execute :

```
public void ShowMenu(View v){

        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.spinner_action);
        popup.show();
    }
```

and the function displays the orginal items in **spinner_actio.xml** and their orginal settings so the definition `android:enabled ="false"`  cancels the actions was done in `showAlertDialog()`.

In order to solve the problem i did the simple following change :

In `showPopup` i checked the `adapter.getCount` - if is equal to `0` (*means - no* *items in the spinner*) so i should enabled *edit & delete* options, but if `adapter.getCount` is bigger than `0` - i set the `enabled` to `true` and now the items are available.

Here my final `ShowMenu()` code :

```
public void ShowMenu(View v){

        popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
        popup.inflate(R.menu.spinner_action);

        Menu popupMenuItems = popup.getMenu();

        if(adapter.getCount() == 0){
            popupMenuItems.findItem(R.id.menu_edit).setEnabled(false);
            popupMenuItems.findItem(R.id.menu_delete).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else{
            popupMenuItems.findItem(R.id.menu_edit).setEnabled(true);
            popupMenuItems.findItem(R.id.menu_delete).setEnabled(true); 
        }
        popup.show();
    }
```

Comment: Glad I could help out a bit.  I make these types of mistakes more than I want to admit.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `PopupMenu` popup more than once.  Once globally at the top of the class and a second time locally in `ShowMenu`.  So you have two popup objects.

You inflate and show the local popup menu created in `ShowMenu`. In `ShowAlertDialog` the code works with the globally declared popup which does not have the inflated view attached to it.

Remove the classtype `PopupMenu` from the statement in `ShowMenu`.

Second, in `ShowAlertDialog`, you did not get the Menu object from popup object(the popup menu) and assign it to popupMenu object(of type `Menu`). Thus, your `setEnabled` code does nothing.

```
 popupMenu = popup.getMenu();
```

You should use an IDE such as Eclipse when coding. It will flag all of these errors.

Comment: Thank you @Reenactor Rob for your answer.You're right i have the errors you mentiomed , i changed my code as you wrote but this was not working.  I had an logic issue in my code, so after thinking a lot of this i got the solution - and i posted it below, anyway thank you!!!