# I need to hide/show a particular item from popup menu on given condition

Tags: java, android

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392916/hide-item-from-popupmenu), but it doesn't work as I expected. 
Here is my code, and this is what i have tried.

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(TableActivity.this, view);
              popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(TableActivity.this);
              menu = popup.getMenu();
              popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_shift);
              popup.show();
              popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);

    @Override
     public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_merge:
                    if(tableDbList.get(positionShift).getMergeTableId()== 0) {     
                      //this is the condition to show/hide popup menuitem  
                         popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_merge).setVisible(false);
                    }else {   
                    checkPinCode.checkPinCodemethod(TableActivity.this,   "mergeCancel");
                    }
         }
     return true;
    }
```

Comment: Call `popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item).setVisible(true/false);` before `popup.show();` . Thats all you need . Whats the issue ?

Comment: It's not working @AD

Comment: Did you get any error ?

Comment: No, I didn't got any error. Instead it didn't hide the item. But if i check the condition before popup.show it gives nullpointerexception.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to change `visibility` on `MenuItem` click . It will work but `popupMenu` will dismiss just after click . So it does not make any sense. 
If your requirement is to show items on some condition you should set visibility before `show()`. Below is a simple example .

```
  private void showPopup() {
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, view);
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_shift, popup.getMenu());
    if(someCondition){
        popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_merge).setVisible(false);
    }
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Comment: It's not working, it gives java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.x.Y.xyzActivity$2.onItemLongClick(xyzActivity.java:265)

Comment: Onitemlongclick is not part of this code . This must somewhere else in code . Debug your code and find the culprit.

Comment: I have initialized PopupMenu on  'OnItemLongClick'

Comment: As i said try to debug your code . I can not make any assumption about the error . Just use the method i have provided as answer. If still getting error the add the code snippet and error in question .

Comment: I have tried your way but it doesn't work. And about debugging code "NullPointerException" is not the problem here. The 'main' problem here is I am trying to hide/show the popup menu item on given condition and its not working

Comment: Well read answer carefully . It's tested code . If you put condition this way it will work .

Comment: If you still stuck .then you need to post your code . Edit your question with tried code . And post relevant code do not just post a method .